# System Admin with View All permissions can not see records -Sandbox

Tags: permissions, sharing, sandbox

We have a new sandbox and are logging in as a System Admin user. The Org Wide Default sharing settings on Accounts (and most objects) is Public Read Write. System Admin permissions on Account are View All. However, when I run a simple query such as

`Select Id, Name from Account`

I get no results. I thought perhaps no data was imported, so I decided to create my own via the UI. When I started typing in names for the Accounts - the Account names from production started showing up! When I select one, it fills all the information for the account.
Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?

Update: This is a developer sandbox (which I didn't know), so it is not supposed to have data. I guess the question becomes how we see the data that comes up as we input Account names?

I ran the query using the Salesforce inspector.

Comment: What happens when you run this query? : SELECT HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess, MaxAccessLevel FROM UserRecordAccess where UserId = '*System Admin's user ID*' and RecordId = '*Account Record ID returned from the UI*'

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more details.  What tool are you using to execute the query? What happens when you query other objects like Contacts etc?  How did you import data into the sandbox?

Comment: Sounds like you have a browser extension that auto-fills forms with data that you've saved in the browser.

Comment: @DavidCheng this is data from an org that I never logged into! I don't have credentials for the prod org!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments. I guess it really doesn't matter what's going on with the autocomplete, and since I realized that the sandbox was created without data, I'm going to close out this question.